# flask url parameters with spaces generates urls with spaces

Tags: python, url, flask, url-routing, percent-encoding

I'm trying to pass a user supplied string as a Flask URL parameter.
`url_for(func_name, param="string with spaces")` or similar generates a URL with spaces.

If the user enter a string with spaces the generated url has spaces it seems to work.

Also if I enter a URL with `%20` it seems to redirect to a url with spaces.
I thought URLs with spaces were a bad idea.

How do I get it to work right (`url_for` and redirection)?
Or should I just accept it?

P.S. 
Is passing a user supplied string as a parameter safe? If not how should I sanitize the user input string?

Comment: This is your browser showing you spaces; everything is working as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Flask generates URLs properly URL encoded; demoing with an existing application:

```
>>> with app.test_request_context('/'):
...     print url_for('core.city', city='new york')
... 
/new%20york
```

Your *browser* on the other hand may elect to show such URLs *decoded* for ease of reading.

`url_for()` quotes input to be URL-safe; encoded URLs cannot contain values that could be interpreted as HTML, so you are safe there as far as user-supplied values are concerned.

Comment: I just tries copy/paste and it looks like you are right. OTOH when I add random junk to the end my 404 page which displays the request.url has space not %20 s. Weird.